# Recursive - I cannot understand how it really works

Tags: c++, recursion

I can't understand something about the recursive function. Let's assume that i'm calculating the factorial of an x number. The code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int y){
    if(y == 0)
        return 1;
    return y * factorial(y-1);


}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << factorial(n);



    return 0;
}
```

And there, from my understanding, i have an base case, which will stop the function at one point. Good until now, after the base case, the next statement will return the x * factorial(x-1).
Lets assume that we want to find the factorial of number "4". It will look something like that:

```
x = 5 --> x != 0, return 5 * factorial(4) | 
x = 4 --> x != 0, return 4 * factorial(3) | 
x = 3 --> x != 0, return 3 * factorial(2) |
x = 2 --> x != 0, return 2 * factorial(1) |
x = 1 --> x != 0, return 1 * factorial(0) |
```

And now, because x equals 0, the next statement will run:

```
if(x == 0)
  return 1;
```

What i don't understand:  if the function return 1, the program should return exactly the number "1", why and how it return what was calculated on the recursive statement.

Comment: Have you debugged the code? A step in debugging is much helpful!

Comment: You seem to have forgotten you'r e still in a call stack six functions deep when you hit that final `return 1;`. Start unwinding back, retaining each calculated return value along the way. It will start making more sense.

Comment: The last return only returns to the previous call of factorial, which itself returns 1 * 1, then the previous function returns 2 * 1 then the previous returns 3 * 2 then the previous returns 4 * 3 then the previous and first call finally returns 5 * 4. In other words the last return doesn’t returns into main, it returns to the location it was called which is in factorial.

Comment: Each recursive call of the function returns exactly once.   Either for the base case or for the other case.   The base case occurs for the deepest recursive call.   The other case occurs for all but the deepest recursive call.   So a call of `factorial(2)` goes to the non-base case and calls `factorial(1)`, which goes to the non-base case and calls `factorial(0)` which hits the base case and returns `1`.  The process then reverses.

Comment: I think the problem is that for some reason you assume that `return` does end the program or something, instead of a single invocation of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1) x = 5 --> x != 0, return 5 * factorial(4) | 
2) x = 4 --> x != 0, return 4 * factorial(3) | 
3) x = 3 --> x != 0, return 3 * factorial(2) |
4) x = 2 --> x != 0, return 2 * factorial(1) |
5) x = 1 --> x != 0, return 1 * factorial(0) |
```

factorial(0) will return 1; hence line 5) will be as follows:

5. `x = 1 --> x != 0, return 1 * 1` |  which is `factorial(1)`

`factorial(1)` will return `1`; hence line 4) will be as follows:

4. `x = 2 --> x != 0, return 2 * 1` | which is `factorial(2)`

`factorial(2)` will return `2`; hence line 3) will be as follows:

3. `x = 3 --> x != 0, return 3 * 2` | which is `factorial(3)`

`factorial(3)` will return `6`; hence line 2) will be as follows:

2. `x = 4 --> x != 0, return 4 * 6` | which is `factorial(4)`

`factorial(4)` will return `24`; hence line 1) will be as follows:

1. `x = 5 --> x != 0, return 5 * 24` | 120

[image: See figure for visualization]

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can add some more visualizations to your code to make the process more visible in the output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void indent(int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i) {
        std::cout << "  ";
    }
}

int factorial(int y, int max){
    indent(max - y);
    std::cout << "calling factorial(" << y << ")" << std::endl;

    if(y == 0) {
        indent(max - y);
        std::cout << "returns 1" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    auto ret = y * factorial(y-1, max);
    indent(max - y);
    std::cout << "returns " << ret << std::endl;
    return ret;


}

int factorial(int y) {
    return factorial(y, y);
}

int main() {
    // int n;
    // cin >> n;

    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n) {
        std::cout << "\nstart\n";
        cout << factorial(n) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
start
calling factorial(0)
returns 1
1

start
calling factorial(1)
  calling factorial(0)
  returns 1
returns 1
1

start
calling factorial(2)
  calling factorial(1)
    calling factorial(0)
    returns 1
  returns 1
returns 2
2

start
calling factorial(3)
  calling factorial(2)
    calling factorial(1)
      calling factorial(0)
      returns 1
    returns 1
  returns 2
returns 6
6

start
calling factorial(4)
  calling factorial(3)
    calling factorial(2)
      calling factorial(1)
        calling factorial(0)
        returns 1
      returns 1
    returns 2
  returns 6
returns 24
24
```

On [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xoYvxsG4s)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for help. With your comments, and a video, i've understood.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCPkszeKRa4 - The video.
Have a great day!, all of you. =).

Answer (score 0):

It is like a child asking questions, like: *What are clouds made of?*

> A. Mostly servers

> Q. What are servers?

> A. Computers that are setup to send you specific data when you request them from your computer.

> Q. What are computers?

> A. Machines that perform calculations.

So that when the question finally gets answered, it is pieced together from the results of many nested questions

> Clouds are made of [[Machines that perform calculations] that are setup to send you specific data when you request them from your [machine that performs calculations].

The issue is that you don't "know" the answer to the question, all you know is another question. So when you finally get to an answer that isn't another question, only then can you backtrack to answer each previous question, in order to finally answer the original question.

Comment: How can this be an "answer" to the original question? This should be a comment at most.